# Using shared pointers with memory allocated in another function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some legacy-era code at work that takes in a double-pointer and allocates memory to it. A shortened example of it would look something like this:

```
struct LegacyObj
{
    int a;
    double b;
};

void LegacyAllocator(LegacyObj** ppObj)
{
    *ppObj = (LegacyObj*)malloc(sizeof(LegacyObj));
}

void LegacyDeleter(LegacyObj** ppObj)
{
    free(*ppObj);
}
```

The actual LegacyAllocator function is ~100 lines and mixes reading from files with creating a linked list of LegacyObj pointers, and isn't something I'd be able to get away with rewriting right now. I would like, however, to make the use of this function a bit safer, avoiding any memory leaks that may occur from exceptions &tc. The first solution I came up with was to wrap it up in a class and handle calling the legacy functions in the ctor/dtor.

```
class RAIIWrapper
{
public:
    RAIIWrapper()
        :obj{nullptr}
    {
        ::LegacyAllocator(&obj);
    }
    RAIIWrapper(RAIIWrapper&& that)
        : obj{ that.obj}
    {
        that.obj = nullptr;
    }
    RAIIWrapper& operator=(RAIIWrapper&& that)
    {
        RAIIWrapper copy{std::move(that)};
        std::swap(obj, copy.obj);
        return *this;
    }
    ~RAIIWrapper ()
    {
        ::LegacyDeleter(&obj);
    }

private:
    LegacyObj* obj;
};
```

But I'm curious - is there a way to do this using `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`? I've not been able to come up with a solution without having to keep the original pointer passed to LegacyAllocator around.

Comment: `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` don't take allocators, they only take deleters. You would allocate the pointer yourself with `LegacyAllocator(&obj)` and make a deleter functor for the `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` which calls `LegacyDeleter(&p)` in its `operator()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom deleter with [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), for example:

```
struct Deleter {
  void operator()(LegacyObj *p) const {
    LegacyDeleter(&p);
  }
};

std::unique_ptr<LegacyObj, Deleter> MakeLegacyObj() {
  LegacyObj *p = 0;
  LegacyAllocator(&p);
  return std::unique_ptr<LegacyObj, Deleter>(p);
}

std::unique_ptr<LegacyObj, Deleter> p = MakeLegacyObj();
```

And, as correctly pointed out by @Dave, this works with `shared_ptr` too:

```
std::shared_ptr<LegacyObj> p = MakeLegacyObj();
```

Comment: and `std::shared_ptr<LegacyObj> p = MakeLegacyObj();` works too

Comment: Thanks, looks like creating a custom deleter functor was what I missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unique_ptr` to delete the memory, but you'll have to provide a custom `Deleter` class since the memory is allocated using `malloc` rather than `new`.

Better yet, change the allocation code to use `new` instead and just use `unique_ptr`.  If you go down this road you can just have the allocator return a `unique_ptr` instead of a pointer to the memory.

Assuming you need to provide your own custom deleter, here is one way you might do it:

```
template <typename T>
class MallocDeleter
{
public:
  void operator() (T* obj) const
  {
    LegacyDeleter (*obj);
  }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr <LegacyObj, MallocDeleter <LegacyObj>> unique_legacy_ptr;
```

You could also probably provide a `make_unique_legacy` type function which allocates by calling  `LegacyAllocator`, instead of having to initialize the `unique_ptr` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a factory function for `unique_ptr`s like this:

```
typedef void(* LegacyDeleterType)(LegacyObj*);
typedef std::unique_ptr<LegacyObj,LegacyDeleterType> UniqueLegacyPtr;

UniqueLegacyPtr makeUniqueLegacyObj()
{
    LegacyObj * p = nullptr;
    LegacyAllocator( &p );
    return UniqueLegacyPtr( p, [](LegacyObj*p){ LegacyDeleter(&p); } );
}
```

You can now use that to create `unique_ptr`s and you can also assign to `shared_ptr`s which capture the custom deleter automatically at construction:

```
int main()
{
    auto unique = makeUniqueLegacyObj();
    std::shared_ptr<LegacyObj> shared = makeUniqueLegacyObj();
}
```